# Export Documents and Data from iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, data-synchronization, data-transfer

When I plug in my iPad to iTunes 12 on Windows, it shows Documents and Data occupies about 8 GB. I would like to export all these documents to my computer so I can delete them from Ipad.

I clicked on the Apps Section in iTunes and tried the File Sharing section. But it does not show all the documents. How do I go transferring them?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation would be to check what's taking up your data. To do this:

1. On your iPad go to Settings
2. Tap on General
3. Tap on Storage and iCloud Usage
4. Under the Storage options tap on Manage Storage
5. Wait a little while for **all** the apps to be populated
6. Once it stops updating, your apps will be listed in order of what's taking up most of the space
7. Tap on the apps in the list to view more details about what's taking up space

By following the above process you'll get a much better idea of what's taking up space and will be able to take steps to manage that.